# select meaningful part out of a signal (for goertzel)

Tags: signal-analysis, algorithms, preprocessing

1. I have an on going input signal, most of the time with no activity.
2. Once in a while there is an activity (oscillations in different freq).
3. I need to take **good** 205 samples out of the signal. 
   what i mean by **good**?
   really oscillating signal for 205 samples (not just crossing threshold).

here is an image to clarify:
[image: oscillating signal]
bubble 1 - not good selection.
bubble 2 - good selection.

I need an efficient way with low computation complexity (for example STFT is heavy), to measure signal's sections oscillation level and chose the best one for further processing, someone knows?

Comment: can you set a amplitude threshold and a minimum "reaching counts" at the threshold within a given time?

Comment: Actually i thought about something like this, first crossing a certain threshold, then count crossing above positive threshold and below negative threshold, but i wonder if there is other way more common.